# Encrypted Calldata

Tags: solidity, etherscan

https://bscscan.com/tx/0x1b30d12030e384eea6c608f28c889eb945e5e80c880c2ebd648b88aea3187bd0
I have found an account that sends encrypted calldata to a contract and then contract makes swap on PancakeSwap. The contract uses 0x2cf6ae00 method for buying with 2 parameters. I think the first one is encrypted address and the second one is buy amount. How the contract knows which contract to call ? Are there any encryption method in Solidity or the developes wrote it himself ?

Comment: Everything in an Ethereum blockchain is public it doesn't make sense to encrypt data since that will be processed on chain. Since the contract source isn't available the only option to determine what the input data represent is to reverse engineer the contract execution. You can start by using a tool like tenderly.co for example.

Comment: I think there is a reason for that. My friend has a copy trading bot that listens transactions for specific account and when copies the transaction and front-runs it. We thought that to prevent to be front-runned , he encrypts the address of the pair contract that he wants to buy and sends to his contract. I think he has a decrpytion function in contract because the first parameter is not address. Addresses are right-padded. He decrypts the encoded address and call this address with specified amount in the calldata

Comment: It doesn't look encrypted, it has too many zeros. In any case it seems it is 'xoring' the first address (luna token) with 0xfff..fff.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's what I meant with "encrypted". I couldn't resolve the token address from the calldata and I thought he wrote a special encoding function for himself

Comment: Did you guess it or when you have seen that immediately find out that it is "xored" ?

Comment: Looking at the start of the address involved you could see there was some relationship 4c4c3c.. and b3b3c3.. tried xor and it returned ffffff, then tried the same for the whole 20 bytes and it worked. In any case depending on the call data for that kind of things would be easy to break.